# Reading Keycloak OmniAuth::AuthHash elements with Ruby 2.7

Tags: ruby, omniauth

From the Keycloak authentication token, I read the OmniAuth::AuthHash elements to extract the user's name, email and roles.
Reading the name and email are quite easy based on the token retrieved through `auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]` statement.
Digging into the token's hierarchy provides requested information:

```
  user.name = auth.info.name
  user.uuid = auth.uid
  user.provider = auth.provider
  user.email = auth.info.email
```

I use the same method to search for user's roles list:

`roles = auth.extra.raw_info.resource_access` provides the following AuthHash:

```
#<OmniAuth::AuthHash 
    BFS.SIS=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash 
        roles=#<Hashie::Array 
            ["dataproducer", 
            "fsodataconsumer", 
            "sisdatasteward"]
            >
        > 
    BFS.SIS.DAL=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash 
        roles=#<Hashie::Array 
            ["kd_getLoadReports", 
            "kd_createTables", 
            "kd_readTables", 
            "kd_deleteTables"]
            >
        > 
    BFS.SIS.DPS.KEYSTORE=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash 
        roles=#<Hashie::Array 
            ["keymanagement_key_read", 
            "keymanagement_keystore_read"]
            >
        > 
    BFS.SIS.SMS=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash 
        roles=#<Hashie::Array 
            ["kdDatasetInformation_read", 
            "codeLists_update", 
            "definedVariables_set_status_validation_in_progress", 
            "hierarchicalCodeLists_update", 
            "hierarchicalCodeLists_create", 
            "kdDatasetInformation_delete", 
            "kdDatasetInformation_update", 
            "kdDataStructureDefinitions_create", 
            "kdDataStructureDefinitions_update", 
            "kdDataStructureDefinitions_delete", 
            "kdDataStructureDefinitions_read",
            "kdDatasetInformation_create", 
            "definedVariables_set_status_open_from_rejected"]
            >
        > 
    BFS.SIS.UI=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash 
        roles=#<Hashie::Array 
        ["bfs.sis.portal"]
        >
    >
>
```

**There is the issue:** as key names contain a '.', I cannot continue accessing subkeys with the syntax key.subkey to retrieve the array of roles for the BFS.SIS and BFS.SIS.SMS keys.

How could I extract the arrays from these keys?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I can't dig into the hash key.subkey syntax, but I can enumerate the subkeys. And then I can check if some match with needed entries, and extract child roles.

Here is the solution I implemented:

```
  auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  roles = Array.new
  activities = auth.extra.raw_info.allowlists.statisticalActivities
  resources_accesses = auth.extra.raw_info.resource_access
  resources_accesses.each do |access|
    puts access # Provides the resources_access hash
    puts access[0] # Provides the resources_access label
    puts access[1] # Provides the resources_access roles array
    # Check if label matches needed entries
    if ["BFS.SIS.SMS", "BFS.SIS", "BFS.SIS.SCHEDULER"].include? access[0].to_s
      access[1].roles.each do |role|
        # Store each role in the roles array
        roles << role
      end
    end
  end
```

This list of roles for a user will help building the list of abilities for CanCanCan gem.